# How to set an ID to a Webix datatable's subview

Tags: javascript, datatable, subview, webix

Is there a way to set the unique ID to the Webix subview? 
As far as I can see, it takes a consistent ID like `$datatableIndex`, but I can't find how to set it programmatically. 
Currently, I'm using a datatable with another datatable inside, something like:

```
webix.ui({
  view:"datatable",  
  subview:{        
    view:"datatable",    
    on:{
      onItemClick:function(id){
        console.log("Subview id: "+this.config.id);
      }
    }
  }      
  ...
});
```

[Sample](http://webix.com/snippet/081aefcd)

But the subview creates on the first expand, so I don't see any obvious way to set an ID to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply add the ID you want in the onSubViewCreate event. Based on your [sample](http://webix.com/snippet/081aefcd) :

```
on:{
    onSubViewCreate:function(view, item){
        view.parse(item.outlets);
        view.config.id = 'test';
    }
}
```

All you have to do is finding a way to properly set a unique ID instead of my 'test' one. Maybe like this:

```
on:{
    onSubViewCreate:function(view, item){
        view.parse(item.outlets);
        view.config.id = item.subview_id; // you need to add this new property to your data
    }
}
```